# Handling Conditional Logic When an Array Has One Value Even If It's an Empty String?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, mongoose, conditional-statements

I have a situation where a user can type a ZIP code value in order to filter some data. I also have this filter set up so that the last values are kept, so that if the user re-enables the filter, those values are available to immediately filter the data again when the filter is re-enabled.

The problem I'm running into is that my filter value is being passed even when the filter's been cleared out. Because this is an array of values passed to Mongoose/MongoDB from our Angular app via the body of a POST request, what effectively get's filtered on is `['']`. And that returns me zero results - not surprsingly.

So I am trying to come up with some conditional checks to prevent the filter from firing when the result is `['']`. I can't simply exclude based on array.length, because even this value is considered an array with a length of 1 - which would also be the case if an actual zip code were there `['77799']`. This is what I've tried doing:

```
    if ( zipArray !== [] && zipArray !== [''] && zipArray[0] !== '') {   
      console.log(zipArray);
      console.log(zipArray.length);
      this.sendZipcode.emit(zipArray);
    }
```

What else could I try here to exclude emitting the value when `zipArray === ['']`, that would still accept an array with a value like `['77799']`? Can I check on a minimum number of characters in whatever element is present in the array? Suggestions?

Comment: `zipArray === ['']` won't do what you think it does. It compares references, and `zipArray` will never equal a new array.

Comment: So how would you suggest I conditionally exclude a result of [''] from being passed?

Comment: `zipArray[0] !== ''` works.

Comment: I have that now if you look above. Doesn't seem to prevent the emitting of the value.

Comment: because of your other two conditions. They fail and thus the whole is false. Get rid of them

Comment: Oh, right. Because of the '&&'s. Thanks, will give this a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the undesired values from the array using `filter` and then check if you still have valid zipcodes to send to your server:

```
let zipArrayWithNoEmptyZip = zipArray.filter(zip => zip.length > 0);
if (zipArrayWithNoEmptyZip.length > 0) {   
  console.log(zipArrayWithNoEmptyZip);
  console.log(zipArrayWithNoEmptyZip.length);
  this.sendZipcode.emit(zipArrayWithNoEmptyZip);
}
```

Comment: What is the second .length measuring here?

Comment: 1st length checks the zipcode string, the 2nd checks if the filtered array is not empty

Comment: Correct! My first intention was to send the filtered array, which I did not do. Let me updated :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution as well. After researching, I see ".find" would also be a valid solution, as @Li357 points out.

Comment: Would be `if (zipArray.find(zip => zip.length > 0) !== undefined)` then keep your code. I prefer a solution with filtering, which sends clean array to your server.